# How to add subdirectory in google cloud storage using flask in python 2

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Im using cloudstorage module for uploading files to google cloud storage since am using python 2.x. And I need to create a subdirectory in my bucket and list all the contents in webpage.

Answer (score 1):

You *don't* create directories in Google Cloud Storage (GCS).

GCS is a flat namespace.

GCS buckets contain objects and object names may include "/".

See [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/HowSubdirectoriesWork) for more details.

`gsutil` and the Console browser make it appear as if buckets contain directories.